# Is my supremum inequality proof correct?

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

I have the following statement to prove: $$[\forall x \in A : f(x) \le g(x)] \implies \sup\{f(x),x\in A\} \le  \sup\{g(x),x\in A\}$$

My proof goes as follows: I will prove the contrapositive. Let $c_0 =  \sup\{f(x),x\in A\} $ and $c_1 =  \sup\{g(x),x\in A\}$. Since $c_0 > c_1$ and $c_1 \ge g(x)$, $c_0 > g(x)$. This means that $c_0$ is an upper bound of $g(x)$ and the supremum of $f(x)$ for any $x\in A$. Since $c_0$ is not the least upper bound of $g(x)$, it follows that $$\exists\ x \in A:f(x)>g(x)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing too fast. You're missing to state that

> if $c_0>c_1$, then, by the properties of the supremum, there exists $x_0\in A$ with $c_1<f(x_0)\le c_0$.

Actually this is a complete proof, because $g(x)\le c_1$ for every $x\in A$ and therefore $g(x_0)<f(x_0)$.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks :)